# Vertical Alignment of multiple blocks

Tags: vertical-alignment

> *Original question*:
>
> ich würde gerne verschiedene Textblöcke vertikal anordnen, vfill bzw. vspace orientiert sich aber nicht an den Seitenrändern, was ich gerne hätte.
>   Also "50%" soll genau mittig der Seite stehen. Weiterführende Frage (Seite 2), kann ich absolute Prozentzahlen angeben?

**Translation**

I'd like to align different text blocks vertically. I'd like `vfill` resp. `vspace` to use the margins for orientation. I'd like to have *50%* be placed in the middle of the page.

Furthermore: can I declare absolute percentages?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{showframe}% blendet Seitenränder ein

\begin{document}

\missingfigure{}

\vfill

50\%

\vfill

\newpage

\missingfigure{}

10\%

95\%

\newpage

dummy

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please write in english here!

Comment: See http://www.deesaster.org/blog/index.php?/archives/2299